# How to configure network proxy server to allow access for Wuala application in windwos 7

Tags: networking, wuala

In my workgroup, the LAN network traffic goes thru a proxy server and that blocks [Wuala](https://www.wuala.com) to work properly.

I need to know which port/how to configure the proxy server to allow Wuala usage for my group.

If you know how to, please share. Thank you!

p.s. I made some [google searches](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=what%20port%20to%20open%20to%20allow%20access%20for%20Wuala%20application%20in%20windwos%207&oq=what%20port%20to%20open%20to%20allow%20access%20for%20Wuala%20application%20in%20windwos%207&aqs=chrome..69i57.12392j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=what%20port%20to%20open%20to%20allow%20access%20for%20Wuala%20application%20in%20windows%207&start=10) though I would find little helps there.

[image]

[image]